# Is it correct to remove multiple similar player from analysis?

Tags: game-theory

I want to analyze a game consist of multiple players with same goal but different features, e.g., a war of attrition with 10-players of different powers. Is it correct to eliminate 8 players and analyze the 2-players game, and then apply results (including, Nash equilibrium strategy profile) to 10-player game?

When it is correct? and when not?

Comment: Could you be more specific? In general, it is not ok to eliminate even identical players, ad they might not play identically.

Comment: My interested game is a game in which some players compete to gain some common utility (e.g. 100 dollars) in a repeated game. In each round, it is possible for each player to get some share of other ones. I read some paper which analyse this game and use such simplification (ignore all but only two players), I want to know is it correct?

Comment: Then I guess it is modeled in a way that each player plays against an "aggregate strategy" of the others. In other words, if players $1,2,3$ try to grab $v_i,v_2,v_3$, then the player 4 responds to an aggregate $\sum_{i=1}^3 v_i $ strategy. But it is crucial that those could be added. 
A link to a paper would be most helpful.